# CoreStore how to fetch or query object from unspecified dynamic object

Tags: ios, core-data, corestore

`enter code here`I read this [guide](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/wiki/Fetching-and-querying) which documented pretty good. I need to search through my database and get a record actually execute fetch or query.

Can I search through all records instead of specifying appropriate `From` clause.

For example

```
var undefinedObject = CoreStore.fetchAll(
    From(GoThroughAllMyDataBaseEntities),
    Where("%K == %@", "localId", "some string id")
)

print(undefinedObject.id) // as object will be undefined I need to figure out how to get id property from it.
```

Side note: all my entities are child objects of parent entity which has `id` property.

So let's say I have next entities in `CoreData`:

```
BaseEntity (which includes id)
Playlist
Song
```

in the code above I don't care which will be returned to me I just what to see one that matches this condition: `Where("%K == %@", "localId", "some string id")`

Also my `localId` property in each objects are very unique strings. They are extracted from `NSManagedObjectID`.

So there is no way have the same duplicated identifier localy in `CoreData`

If there is no way to do it, then I will need to loop all my `Playlists` and `Songs` records.

`managedObjectContext.objectWithID(objectID)` may not work thought in some cases as there is no guaranty that `CoreData` record has not been deleted and app recreated a copy of the same record, so physically a copy of record has another `objectID` address in `CoreData`, but still has localID property copied from other record.

Comment: Did you try using From<BaseEntity>(), Where<BaseEntity>....? that should actually work

Comment: @MartinM I have not tried it, but as I understood as BaseEntity is a parent abstract entity it does not have records?

Comment: @MartinM sorry maybe I forget to say that it's an abstract entity

Comment: An abstract entity means that you cannot create one. But you should still be able to get the ones that reflect to its type.

Comment: @MartinM oh ok, I got it thanks for suggestion! I will try